# Creating New Model Form Fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I have a product model that has a `manytomany` relationship to a `locations` model.  I am creating an app for my clients business that has hundreds of products and services, but each product/service have different prices base on the delivery location and can deliver to multiple locations. Right now my client delivers to 4 locations.

**Solution #1**
Hard code all 4 locations into the product model - this works, but is not preferred since they want to expand and hard coding more locations is just gross..

**Solution #2 (current solution - code listed below)**
Create a manytomany relationship to locations - this works, but is getting way out of hand having location options of varying charges an rates for - multiplied by every product....

**Solution #3 - This is the help I need, if a solution exists.**
I would like to build a hybrid of sort of the above two options. Id like to keep the manytomany with the location model so its easy to add locations as they grow, but once added, I would like to have an empty 'price' object that they can fill-in when adding or updating a product, yet remain assigned to that product only.

Not sure if this makes sense, so after my current code below (solution 2 above) I included a sample image to help illustrate my question.  Thank you for your help.

**Product Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('Location', related_name='deliver_to')
    ...
```

**Location Model**

```
LOCATIONS = (
    ('Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles'),
    ('Orange County', 'Orange County'),
    ('Riverside', 'Riverside'),
    ('San Diego', 'San Diego')

)


class Location(models.Model):
    l_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=LOCATIONS,
        verbose_name='Service Location'
    )
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: I may not be able to help as I'm definitely a Django amateur, but just to clarify what you're trying to do . . . so you envision the user typing in a price in that blank field above? Or is that field for the new location name? Does the plus sign on the right take you to a new page with a form or something? Or does the plus sign submit whatever you have typed into that form field?

Answer (score 0):

Using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany will allow for extra fields.